# ExtJs 4 - Copy records from store to treestore (grid to treegrid)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

First of all: I'm using ExtJs 4.2.1

I have two grids: the first one collects records from a database (countries) and the second is a treegrid (should show countries and each country should expand a list of cities).

The behaviour I'm trying to achieve is that once you select a record (or multiple records) on the first grid, those records are copied to the treegrid as leafs so then I can fill those leafs with more records (cities).

I get the records from the first grid with:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()
```

But I don't know how to copy them on the treegrid. I've tried using setRootNode and I can see the records on the "raw" property of the root node but I'm not able to show them on the grid.

What am I missing?

---

**Updated**: I've manage to get the countries with:

```
var records = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
treegrid.getStore().setRootNode({ root: true, expanded: true, children: records})
```

Now I'm having problems to load the subrecords. As a test I've tried using the same "country records" to make sure there's no conflicts with the model. This is what I've tried:

```
var records = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
for (record in records){
    records[record].expanded = true;
    records[record].children = records;
}
treegrid.getStore().setRootNode({ root: true, expanded: true, children: records})
```

This should show a list of countries and when expanding one of the records, it should show again the list as children of the selected record. It's not working :(

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes, but the solution got too heavy so I decided to put everything together on the backend and sent the whole thing back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I didn't liked the solution so eventually I constructed the whole thing on the backend but it was working.

Using insert/appendChild as Reimius said wasn't working since my records were not nodes so I had to loop over the country array and make each country a node with createNode(). For every country node I created, I looped through its cities, created a node for each one and then used insertChild() to associate it with the country.

Once everything was done I used:

```
treegrid.getStore().setRootNode({ root: true, expanded: true, children: records})
```

With "records" being an array of this monstrous creation of nodes.

Comment: I forgot to post it here because it was so annoying and inefficient that I didn't thought of it as a "real" solution but maybe it points someone on the right direction to build something useful.